# I get this error in my flutter app. migrate this app to the V2 embedding

Tags: flutter

I get this error in my Flutter Project,

C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in source_code...                        34.3s
This app is using a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to migrate this app to the V2 embedding.
Take a look at the docs for migrating an app: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects
The plugin `firebase_core` requires your app to be migrated to the Android embedding v2. Follow the steps on https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration and re-run this command.
Process finished with exit code 1

[Flutter Embedding Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI8eK.png)

Comment: Visit the github link mentioned in the error log. It has a guide on how you can migrate the app to use new android embedding. The issue happens on projects created quite some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

Since Flutter 1.12 the way how Flutter plugins communicate with the native Android side has been improved. Allowing plugins to better integrate with the native Android lifecycle.

Some plugins support both the new and the old structure, however many plugins (like `firebase_core`) dropped support for the legacy structure to ensure optimal integration with the Android system.

Apps created using Flutter 1.12 and higher automatically generate the correct Android integration logic, however Flutter applications created with an earlier version of Flutter need to be manually migrated. There are two options to fix this for your app:

1. The easiest solution is to delete the `android` folder in your project and let Flutter (using Flutter 1.12 or higher) recreate it for you by running the following command in the root folder of the Flutter project: `flutter create --platform=android .` (don't forget the `.` at the end of the command). You should only do this if you haven't made any custom changes to the Android code and of course make sure to make a backup first.
2. The more safe option is to manually migrate the Android project using the instructions provided on the [GitHub Wiki](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects) page mentioned in the error message.

When following the instructions on the GitHub Wiki page make sure to keep an eye on all the details. Personally I forgot to update the `<application android:name="MyApp"` to the recommended `<application android:name="${applicationName}"` which resulted in the same error you are reporting.

What helped me was to create a new "dummy" application with the latest version of Flutter (for example `flutter create --platforms=android test_app`) and compare the files in the Android folder with the files of my current App and make changes where necessary.